# How to get the value in result.rows[0] as a string?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am querying a Cassandra database using Node.js, and receiving `result`. I can access each element of the result with `result.rows[0]` etc.

However, I am currently trying to do data processing of the result in Javascript. I tried to convert `result.rows[0]` to String with `result.rows[0].data.toString()` but this returned error `Cannot read property toString of undefined`.

I know that I do indeed have data in my `result.rows[0]`. What is the problem in this situation, and how would I go about acquiring the String contained in `result.rows[0]`? I have also tried getting `toString()` of `result` yet that is returning `[object Object]`.

Comment: Try this result.rows[0].toString()

Comment: What that error means is that `result.rows[0].data` is undefined, so it couldn't call `toString` on it. Perhaps all you want to do is call re... what nikhil said ^

Comment: I will double check the contents of `result.rows[0].data`. I tried @nikhil's suggestion and the returned String is "[object Object]" (I verified this by slicing the first character off the String, I got "object Object]"

Comment: If result.rows[0] is an object then, do one thing console.dir(result.rows[0]), will give you details. Check console and please share findings.

Comment: I called `console.dir(result.rows[0])` and there is data in there. Cannot disclose exact data for privacy reasons, but it looks something like this: `{date: "2015-06-10" color: "red" etc. etc.}`

Comment: `[object Object]` is indeed the string form of any object in javascript. You could get the json format, though i'm not sure if that's what you're looking for. `JSON.stringify(result.rows[0])`

Comment: `JSON.stringify` looks like it could work - I will update my regex since the returned string has some characters escaped out.